# Regex First Instance Before a Known String but After Repeating String

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am working on a regex problem that I can't crack. I have a list of strings that looks something like this:

`"Some Leading Words, "ind": "ind1", "primary":true, some more words, "ind": "ind2", "primary":false"`

I would like to pull back the primary indicator. In this case, that would be `ind1`. This can be accomplished with:

`\bind\b(.*?)"primary":true`

Or at least this gets close...I still have the "ind" and the "primary:true" part, but I am actually doing this in Excel using the VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 library so I can `RIGHT`, `LEFT`, `MID` and `SEARCH` my way around things I know I don't want to include.

The trouble that I have is when the primary indicator is second in the string.

`"Some Leading Words, "ind": "ind1", "primary":false, some more words, "ind": "ind2", "primary":true`

On this one, I end up with everything between the first `ind` and the `"primary":true` which is more than I want.

(FYI: I parsing JSON from the [NPI API site](https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api/demo) and need to return each physicians primary taxonomy if that context helps out.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here's one idea.  Include the comma before the `"primary":true` and then change the dot `.` to be a character class that allows anything except a comma.

```
\bind\b([^,]*?), "primary":true
```

That will give you what you want.

But, if you don't want the extra stuff along with your value, you can use something like this:

```
\bind\b": "([^,]*?)", "primary":true
```

[Here is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/sV8pL0/1)

Comment: Bingo. Appreciate the help.